# a function split strings without using strtok and return a new array

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, heap-memory, c-strings

I'm trying to write a function that split strings and is not allowed to use strtok.

Assume the string only have spaces between the words, and only one space between each pair of words.

I allocate each word and words of array on heap. *However, The result of running the program is :* **Segmentation fault(core dumped)** . Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void displayWords(char *wordArray[], int numWords){
    if (wordArray != NULL){
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<numWords;i++)
            printf("%i. \"%s\"\n", i+1, wordArray[i]);
    
}
}

int countSpaces(char theString[]) {
    int spaces = 0, len = strlen(theString);
    for(int i=0;i < len;i++) {
        if(theString[i] == ' ') {
        spaces++;
    }
}
return spaces;
}

char** splitString(char theString[], int *arraySize){

int i,x,y=0;

int start,end=0; //index;
char *word; //create an array with char as elements
char **words;//create an array with words as its elements

int stringLen=strlen(theString);

int numOfWords = countSpaces(theString)+1;
*arraySize = numOfWords;
word = (char*)malloc(stringLen+1);
words = (char**)malloc(numOfWords);

for(x=0;x<=stringLen;x++){
    if (theString[x]==' ' || theString[x]=='\0'){   
        for(x=start;x<=end;x++){  
            word[y]=theString[x];
            y++; 
            
        strcpy(words[i],word);//copy the substring into words
        words[i] = (char*)malloc(strlen(word)+1);  
            

        i++;
        free(word); 
        start=end+2;  //next start is the element right after the space
        end=end+2;        //do the same thing on end index
        }
    }    
    else{   //when theString[x] != ' '
            end++;
    
    }
}
words[*arraySize]=='\0';

return words;
}

int main(){
    int size;
    char test[]="it is a cat";
    char **words = splitString(test, &size);
    displayWords(words, size);



 
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. > words = (char**)malloc(numOfWords);

This should be :

```
words = malloc(numOfWords*sizeof(char*));
```

If you donot specify the `sizeof(char*)`, required amount of memory might not be allocated. So, you may end up accessing unallocated location. This gives you segmentation fault.  There is no need to cast the output of `malloc`

2. > for(x=0;x<=stringLen;x++)

This should be :

```
for(x=0;x<stringLen;x++)
```

3. > for(x=start;x<=end;x++)

`start` has not been initialized. (`int start,end=0; )`